# How to Highlight a Symbolic Link in Finder of El Capitan?

Tags: finder, macos, highlights

You cannot do the highlight in Finder of El Capitan 10.11.4. 
However, there may be other methods to do it.

---

How can you highlight a symbolic link in Finder of El Capitan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your highlight on the original, the symlink will follow - even across different drives on the same machine, even across different machines, so long as they are able to see each other.

Note: Sometimes the changes are not visible immediately to the Finder. Any change to the folder is usually enough to 'remind' it.

Comment: Why cannot you put the highlight to the symlink and then it would change to all others?

Comment: I've no idea, but you can't.

Comment: I tested this proposal now. It does not work in 10.11.5. How did you get it work?

Comment: I'm on 10.11.5 also. If you don't see the change, you need to force a refresh on the Finder window. copy a new file in there, etc... I tested this on a local machine with several internal drives & also across to another shared Mac on the local network. It worked.

Comment: I found the reason for my problem. If you have changed the name of the symbolic link and original source any time. You cannot highlight. After reboot, I also noticed that the symbolic link did not work anymore after such name changes.